# Writing queries to find students' repetitive ages only once even after several students have the same age.

Tags: sql-server

let's say my table is something like this:

student- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

ages- 20,23,24,20,27,27,27,20,20

So over here several students have the same age. How would I write a query in MSSQL so that I'll get all the ages only once like four students are 20 but 20 will appear in my table only once. I want all the ages only once, I don't want them to be repeated in my table.

Comment: I don't understand your table, can you be more clear?

Comment: Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each age once the following should do:

```
Select distinct age from ages
```